# Change update URL for a ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, clickonce

Is it possible to change the update [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to different location of an installed ClickOnce application? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: where do you want to change the update url : from client side or server side ?

Comment: This seems to detail what you want: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/5309f67e-efe4-40b4-b937-aed18cf87155/

Comment: @Cybermaxs-I want to change from the client side. Client already has installed the clickonce app and I need to change the update checking url.

Answer (score 3):

You mention in your comment that you wish to change it "on the client side". This is not possible. Your client app must be able to check for the update at the previous location which will then redirect it to the new location for the immediately next deployment.

See [How to move a ClickOnce deployment](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/how-to-move-a-clickonce-deployment/).

Comment: It is possible to set UNC path using the format \\Server\ApplicationName. So this post You linked to suggests, that I have to know exact place were updates will be located in client's local network at the time I publish my application? And in case client has some changes (a folder renamed for instance) then the only way to change where my application looks for updates would be to make a new installation (with the new update location), reinstalling the old version and installing the new version? Is that right? No way to configure this update path from application side?

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible with a trick.
You can deploy it to the default publish location. (the application shouldn't check for updates). 
Then copy your deployment to the customers server.
Just install your application on the client machines.
The field System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.AbsoluteUri contains the location and .application where the application is installed from. If you know that, then you can simple execute this url.
To check if there is an update, examine the .application file en grape the version.

this is my helper class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace MatemanSC.Utility
{
    public class ClickOnceUtil
    {
        Version _UpdateVersion = null;
        public string UpdateLocation
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.AbsoluteUri;
            }
        }
        public Version AvailableVersion
        {
            get
            {
                if (_UpdateVersion == null)
                {
                    _UpdateVersion = new Version("0.0.0.0");
                    if (System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
                    {
                        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.AbsoluteUri))
                        {
                            //Keep reading until there are no more FieldRef elements
                            while (reader.ReadToFollowing("assemblyIdentity"))
                            {
                                //Extract the value of the Name attribute
                                string versie = reader.GetAttribute("version");
                                _UpdateVersion = new Version(versie);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _UpdateVersion;
            }
        }
        public bool UpdateAvailable
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion != AvailableVersion;
            }
        }
        public string CurrentVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
            }
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.UpdateLocation.AbsoluteUri);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        public void CheckAndUpdate()
        {
            try
            {
                if (UpdateAvailable)
                    Update();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this how to use it:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        ClickOnceUtil clickonceutil = new ClickOnceUtil();
        clickonceutil.CheckAndUpdate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the url that you will use to upgrade programs, you can just use url rewrite at web.config: the old program will point to the old url, but it will bring the new program, which will have the new url.